# Cannot install TWRP

Tags: twrp, fastboot, huawei

I am trying to install TWRP on my android phone. My problem is that when I try to flash the img file the download starts but it doesn't get all the way through and just throws command failed at me. Any idea why this might happen?

By the way, I do have an unlocked bootloader, I have spelled the img file name correctly, and I have checked that the device is connected before flashing with `adb devices`.

My phone is the Huawei Honor 8 (FRD-L09), and I am using the SDK platform tools to flash the recovery

The commands are:

```
adb reboot bootloader
fastboot flash recovery img file
```

and then it fails.

Comment: IIRC, Huawei devices starting from Oreo has a `recovery_ramdisk` partition instead of `recovery`, which by the way requires corresponding recovery ramdisk images.

Comment: Would be nice if you include the error that you see. Because without that it's going to be tough.